# Can I butcher a tamed animal that died on its own?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a tame alpaca that died on its own (of hunger I think). Can I butcher it for meat and wool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Dwarfs are superstitious, and will only butcher dead **wild** animals or tame animals that they slaughter themselves via the animals screen.

And by superstitious, I mean, "It's a quirk of the game, don't think too hard, please".

But yes, Alpaccas (and all grass-eaters) can die of starvation; make sure you're pasturing them in a grassy place so they don't starve!